# ASP WebApi - how to handle potential XSS attacks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xss

I'm wondering how best to handle XSS attacks in the ASP.net web-api.  I've got lots of api controllers.  Most of them are posting json to the server.

At what level should we be verifying strings so that they don't include malicious `<script>` tags?

```
public class SomeModel
{
    [NoXssPlease]
    public string SomeProp {get;set;}
}
```

or

```
[Post]
[NoXssPlease] 
public void Post
{

}
```

or do something at a global filter or handler level.  I've been searching for some information on how to tackle this but there are varying opinions on how this should be done.

Comment: Why would you want to decorate only specific actions with `NoXssPlease`, you want to prevent an attack on each of your actions right ?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net Web API AntiXss (https://www.nuget.org/packages/ASPNetWebAPIAntiXss/) is what you want.

After install package add "[Embarr.WebAPI.AntiXss.AntiXss()]" attribute for properties.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I still get html in the model property

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.Net Web API AntiXss use below code to encode and compare with main value in IsValid method:

```
    string encodedValue = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(value.ToString(), false);
```

And this cause if for example '&' exist in main value the validation failed.
The asp.net prevent only '<' character if followed by alphabet character, it will pass '<1' or '< ' values.
The below simple code is an implementation for your AntiXss:

```
public class AntiXss : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string strValue = value.ToString();
            //Regular Expression: ^(?:[^<]|<+[^A-Za-z\/<]|<+$)*$
            int idx = -1;
            while ((idx = strValue.IndexOf('<', idx + 1)) >= 0 && idx + 1 < strValue.Length)
            {
                if (char.IsLetter(strValue[idx + 1]) || strValue[idx + 1] == '/')
                    return new ValidationResult("A potentially dangerous value was detected from the client.");
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```